# Find the leading behavior of $\int_0^\infty \cos \left(x \left(\frac{t^3}{3} - t\right)\right)dt$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, asymptotics

Find the leading behavior of $$\int_0^\infty \cos \left(x \left(\frac{t^3}{3} - t\right)\right)dt$$ for large $x$.

The problem also asks for outlining the method for finding more terms in the asymptotic expansion.

The following hint is provided: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos (ax^2) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin (ax^2) dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2a}}$.

I have not seen a question like this before. Most questions for leading-order behavior involve the exponential function in some way (which isn't immediately apparent here). I suppose that $\cos x$ is related to the exponential in the sense that $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$, but this does not look helpful here.

A Taylor expansion does not necessarily look promising to me either.

Comment: Are you sure that the integrate is for $x$ and not for $t$ ?

Comment: should your integral perhaps be with respect to $t$ instead of $x$?? All the stuff with $t$ is a little redundant otherwise, and can just be replaced with a constant $a$

Comment: This is the Airy function $\text{Ai}(x)$, it can be expressed as a linear combination of $J_{1/3}$ and $J_{-1/3}$, then use the asymptotic formula for bessel function.

Comment: Thanks for those pointing out that I wrote $dx$ instead of $dt$. This has been fixed.

Comment: This is standard stuff from textbooks, boring like hell. Fortunately, it's not _my_ homework.

Comment: @pisco125: This is not the definition of the Airy function.  Rather, that is $$\operatorname{Ai}{(x)} = \frac1{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} dt \, \cos{\left (\frac{t^3}{3} + x t \right )} $$  See http://dlmf.nist.gov/9.5

Comment: @Ron Gordon Thank you for clarifying this. I know there is some subtle difference between the given function and the Airy function, but they're interchangeable via simple transformation. For example, you can change variables in $\text{Ai}(x)$ to make it looks like the integral in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^\infty \cos \left(x \left(\frac{t^3}{3} - t\right)\right)dt$$
Knowing the properties of the Airy functions, the answer is easy :

Let $\begin{cases}T^3=xt^3 \\ zT=xt \end{cases}\quad\to\quad z=x^{2/3}$
$$I=x^{-1/3}\int_0^\infty \cos \left(\frac{T^3}{3} -zT \right)dT=x^{-1/3}\pi \text{Ai}(-z)$$
Ai is the Airy function : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryFunctions.html
$$I=\pi x^{-1/3} \text{Ai}( -x^{2/3} )$$
Equivalent at infinity :  http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/AiryAi/06/02/01/02/

$$\quad \text{Ai}(-z)\sim
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}\: z^{1/4}}\sin\left(\frac{2}{3}z^{3/2}+\frac{\pi}{4} \right) +O\left(\frac{1}{z^{3/2}} \right)$$

$$I=\int_0^\infty \cos \left(x \left(\frac{t^3}{3} - t\right)\right)dt \quad\sim\quad \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{x}}\sin\left(\frac{2}{3}x +\frac{\pi}{4} \right) +O\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)$$